# Play a bag with a step

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to play a Bagfile, but only advertise one message and skip the 2 following.. and there we go.. anyway to do this ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328105/play-a-bag-with-a-step/) by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're describing *subsampling* a topic, correct?

If so: I don't believe that is supported right now.

You could post-process your back yourself using the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook). Only keeping 1 out of 3 messages shouldn't be too hard to implement.

---

Edit:

> Yes, i want to record on an other bag, only 1 out of 3 messages that are published from the original bag. can you tell me more about how can I do it ?

write a Python script that does something like the following:

```
import rosbag

# opening hard-coded filenames here, but you could obviously make this
# a command line option

count = 0
with rosbag.Bag('output.bag', 'w') as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():

        # drop only messages on 'your_topic'
        if topic == "/your_topic":
            # here we drop every 2 out of 3 messages
            if (count % 3 == 0):
                outbag.write(topic, msg, t)

        else:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, t)

        count += 1
```

This is essentially [example 1](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps) combined with [example 5](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Create_a_cropped_bagfile).

I haven't checked this, so it could be that you'd need to tweak this a bit or make some corrections.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on 2019-07-10**:
Yes, i want to record on an other bag, only 1 out of 3 messages that are published from the original bag. can you tell me more about how can I do it ? I don't really understand the utility of the rosbag API you gave me.
Thanks

**Comment by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on 2019-07-10**:
Thanks for the help, I know how to code in Python, but never used a python code with ROS, how do I run the code after editing it ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
It's just Python. There is nothing special about it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
You appear to have removed the comment you posted, but:

> I want to subsample all the topics, so I removed the first If syntax

the code you showed counted *all* messages from *all* topics. So it wasn't skipping 2 msgs from a single topic, but it just counted all msgs and skipped 2 messages from all topics. That leads to many more skipped messages. You'll want to have counters *per topic*.

> 'm getting an error 'No module named 'yaml' ' when It tries to import rosbag. Any idea ?

Perhaps something like #q327808.